# How to place a link button next to a div using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a link button that I need to place to the right of a div. Adding `float-left` on the div and `float-right` on the link button does not do it. What am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/3v2s4c50/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
              <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Today and Tomorrow</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="float-left">Someone somewhere is waiting for you.</div>
                    <a role="button" href="google.com" class="float-right btn btn-primary"> Login</a>
            </div>  
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: float is not what you have to use in such situations, try dividing text and button using `row` and `col` of bootstrap it works

Comment: @keidakida row col approach makes the link button take all the height of the column and make the button look bigger than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah but you can restrict the height of the button, it's the same as using `display: flex` kind of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove floats and add:

```
.card-body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="card-body d-flex">
       <div class="flex-fill">Someone somewhere is waiting for you</div>
       <a role="button" href="google.com" class="flex-fill btn btn-primary"> Login</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is doing it. But the portion of the screen that is showing the results is not wide enough to show both the div with the text and the button in the same row.. then it breaks down.
If you change the text to something smaller, like 'Someone is waiting' you can see the button floating right :)
You can also set a fixed width for your text div (currently it is expanding based on the content).

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="float-left" style="width: 50%;">Someone somewhere is waiting for you</div>
                    <a role="button" href="google.com" class="float-right btn btn-primary"> Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I now notice that in the fiddle. But it would not work the same in my project, probably due to parent div's restrictions. In other words the float solution will not work in all cases. I accepted the answer that fixed it.

Comment: glad you got that fixed, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your link to a div with any class. Then add style "text-align: right;" into your div like this:

```css
.my-link {
     text-align: right;
}
```

```html
.
<div class="my-link">
    <a role="button" href="google.com" class="float-right btn btn-primary"> Login</a>
</div>
.
```

I hope this will be useful.